# How to have 2 different reference sections in a latex file?

Tags: bibtex, multiple-citations, bibunits

I want to have 2 different reference section for a paper, the first one is for the main paper, the second one for the supplementary materials (SM). Currently I am doing something like this:

```
\usepackage{bibunits}

\begin{bibunit}[plain]

*text*

\putbib[apssamp]
\end{bibunit}

\begin{bibunit}[plain]
\newbibstartnumber{50}

*text*

\putbib[apssamp_SM]
\end{bibunit}
```

This almost does what I need, but if I have a reference, say number 10, that appears in the main text and in the SM, when it appears in the SM I want it to be labeled as 10, not as 56 (or wherever number it is in the SM). The approach above relabels the references in the SM that appear already in the main text and this is not what I need. How can I fix that? Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure this is possible with bibunits. Maybe biblatex could achieve this. Or have you found a bibunits solution in the mean time?